# Instance was not initialized, using default configuration

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

1) Bundle identifier same as one at linked apps

2) Using a tester account

3) Window->G Play Games->Setup->Android Setup - done

4) SDK Manager's packages up to date, [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) up to date

5) My setup code(taken from the [Minimal sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/samples/Minimal) and modified a litte bit):

```
void Start()
        {
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
            PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
            Social.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
            {
                Debug.Log(success);
            });

            var config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        }
```

I get the following logcat:

```
05-11 05:52:22.719      666-676/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[240,427][240,427]} from pid 1212
05-11 05:52:22.744     666-1206/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.Toughwin.MemoryRun for activity com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: pid=937 uid=10305 gids={50305, 3003}
05-11 05:52:23.098      937-937/? D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41fdc2c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fdba30 {com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
05-11 05:52:23.103      937-937/? D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{41fdc2c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fdba30 {com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
05-11 05:52:23.114      137-137/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:-1,c:137) setConsumerName: com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
05-11 05:52:23.114      137-137/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:-1,c:137) setDefaultBufferSize: w=854, h=480
05-11 05:52:23.118      666-684/? I/WindowManager﹕ Gaining focus: Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
05-11 05:52:23.197      137-338/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:937,c:137) connect: api=2 producer=(937:com.Toughwin.MemoryRun) producerControlledByApp=true
05-11 05:52:23.197      137-336/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:2,p:937,c:137) new GraphicBuffer needed
05-11 05:52:23.218      137-137/? I/GLConsumer﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e65b30,api:2) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)]
05-11 05:52:23.224      666-684/? I/ActivityManager﹕ [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +491ms
05-11 05:52:23.224      666-684/? D/ActivityManager﹕ AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity:491:152769531
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #06  pc 0049f42c  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #07  pc 0049f2f0  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #08  pc 0049fa98  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #09  pc 002e10e8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #10  pc 004b7c9c  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.370      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #11  pc 004b90a8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.371      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #12  pc 004bde28  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.371      937-963/? E/Unity﹕ [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
    (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 222)
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #06  pc 004a08c0  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #07  pc 004a0c88  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #08  pc 0049f550  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #09  pc 0049fb00  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #10  pc 002e10e8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #11  pc 004b7c9c  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #12  pc 004b90a8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.374      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #13  pc 004bde28  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #06  pc 004a08c0  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #07  pc 004a0ca0  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #08  pc 0049f550  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #09  pc 0049fb00  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #10  pc 002e10e8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #11  pc 004b7c9c  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #12  pc 004b90a8  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.377      937-963/? D/MALI﹕ #13  pc 004bde28  /data/app-lib/com.Toughwin.MemoryRun-1/libunity.so
05-11 05:52:23.391      937-963/? D/Unity﹕ GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_KHR_debug
05-11 05:52:23.569      133-598/? D/FrameworkListener﹕ dispatchCommand data = (getaddrinfo stats.unity3d.com ^ 1024 0 1 0 ^)
05-11 05:52:23.570      133-990/? D/libc-netbsd﹕ res_queryN name = stats.unity3d.com, class = 1, type = 1
05-11 05:52:23.570      133-990/? D/libc﹕ QUERY: RECURSIVE stats.unity3d.com (A)
05-11 05:52:23.634      133-990/? D/libc﹕ QUERY: RECURSIVE stats.unity3d.com (A)
05-11 05:52:23.634      133-990/? D/libc﹕ ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61990
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3
    ;;  stats.unity3d.com, type = A, class = IN
    stats.unity3d.com.  1H IN A     62.116.219.119
    unity3d.com.        44m24s IN NS    ns01.unity3d.com.
    unity3d.com.        44m24s IN NS    ns02.unity3d.com.
    unity3d.com.        44m24s IN NS    ns03.unity3d.com.
    ns01.unity3d.com.   1h44m IN A  62.116.219.114
    ns02.unity3d.com.   1h44m IN A  75.126.59.154
    ns03.unity3d.com.   1h44m IN A  54.248.81.61
    1h3m22ih
05-11 05:52:23.635      133-990/? D/libc﹕ f2 26 81 80 00 01 00 01 00 03 00 03 05 73 74 61  .&...........sta
    74 73 07 75 6e 69 74 79 33 64 03 63 6f 6d 00 00  ts.unity3d.com..
    01 00 01 c0 0c 00 01 00 01 00 00 0e 10 00 04 3e  ...............>
    74 db 77 c0 12 00 02 00 01 00 00 0a 68 00 07 04  t.w.........h...
    6e 73 30 31 c0 12 c0 12 00 02 00 01 00 00 0a 68  ns01...........h
    00 07 04 6e 73 30 32 c0 12 c0 12 00 02 00 01 00  ...ns02.........
    00 0a 68 00 07 04 6e 73 30 33 c0 12 c0 3f 00 01  ..h...ns03...?..
    00 01 00 00 18 60 00 04 3e 74 db 72 c0 52 00 01  .....`..>t.r.R..
    00 01 00 00 18 60 00 04 4b 7e 3b 9a c0 65 00 01  .....`..K~;..e..
    00 01 00 00 18 60 00 04 36 f8 51 3d              .....`..6.Q=
05-11 05:52:23.635      133-990/? D/libc-netbsd﹕ res_queryN name = stats.unity3d.com succeed
05-11 05:52:23.635      937-986/? D/libc-netbsd﹕ getaddrinfo: stats.unity3d.com get result from proxy >>
05-11 05:52:23.637      937-986/? I/System.out﹕ [socket][0] connection stats.unity3d.com/62.116.219.119:80;LocalPort=45598(0)
05-11 05:52:23.637      937-986/? I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[stats.unity3d.com/62.116.219.119:80] tm:90
05-11 05:52:24.318      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.321      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Instance was not initialized, using default configuration.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.412      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.414      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.416      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Creating real IPlayGamesClient
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.496      937-963/? D/GamesUnitySDK﹕ Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
05-11 05:52:24.749      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Entering state: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.750      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.752      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: Entering state: ShutdownState
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.752      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 DEBUG: ShutdownState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:24.762      937-963/? W/Unity﹕ !!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:24 +03:00 WARNING: PlayGamesPlatform already initialized. Ignoring this call.
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:25.024     937-1000/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:25 +03:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:25.093      666-684/? I/WindowManager﹕ Losing focus: Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
05-11 05:52:25.142      937-937/? D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41fdc2c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fdba30 {com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
05-11 05:52:30.209      937-937/? D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41fdc2c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fdba30 {com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
05-11 05:52:30.225      666-684/? I/WindowManager﹕ Gaining focus: Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
05-11 05:52:33.932     937-1000/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:33 +03:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:33.967      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ [Play Games Plugin DLL] 05/11/15 5:52:33 +03:00 DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:52:33.968      937-963/? I/Unity﹕ False
    (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
05-11 05:54:16.504      937-937/? D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41fdc2c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41fdba30 {com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
05-11 05:54:16.557      137-137/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:2,p:937,c:137) setDefaultBufferSize: w=480, h=854
05-11 05:54:16.568      666-684/? I/WindowManager﹕ Losing focus: Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
05-11 05:54:16.622      137-618/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:2,p:-1,c:137) disconnect: api=2
05-11 05:54:16.622      137-618/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:-1,c:137) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffff
05-11 05:54:16.622      137-618/? I/GLConsumer﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e65b30,api:0) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x10000004
05-11 05:54:16.629      137-137/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) consumerDisconnect
05-11 05:54:16.630      137-137/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0xb8e9bab8,id:1863,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueue
05-11 05:54:18.535    666-22270/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
05-11 05:54:18.535    666-22270/? W/WindowManager﹕ Force-removing child win Window{421009f8 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{420f9d90 u0 com.Toughwin.MemoryRun/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
```

Do I miss something? What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS!

**Add a Keystore.**(only if you've uploaded the apk to the dev console)

I was missing to add the keystore to my app, since I uploaded the app to the dev console and in order to be able to upload it, a keystore was needed.