# GooglePlayServices in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to implement google play services into my game but when the level is restarted it starts the google play service login screen.
and also get in the console: `Instance was not initialized, using default configuration.`

Here is the whole log
    `[Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:228)
GooglePlayServices:Awake() (at Assets/Scripts/GooglePlayServices.cs:13)
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: Instance was not initialized, using default configuration.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:get_Instance() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:94)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:229)
GooglePlayServices:Awake() (at Assets/Scripts/GooglePlayServices.cs:13)
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:230)
GooglePlayServices:Awake() (at Assets/Scripts/GooglePlayServices.cs:13)
 [Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:296)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:271)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs:44)
GooglePlayServices:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/GooglePlayServices.cs:19)
[Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: Creating IPlayGamesClient in editor, using DummyClient.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesClientFactory:GetPlatformPlayGamesClient(PlayGamesClientConfiguration) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/PlayGamesClientFactory.cs:30)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:297) [Play Games Plugin DLL] 06/28/15 7:46:20 +03:00 DEBUG: Received method call on DummyClient - using stub implementation.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:58)
GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient:LogUsage() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/BasicApi/DummyClient.cs:185)
GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/BasicApi/DummyClient.cs:28)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:301)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:271)
GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs:44)
GooglePlayServices:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/GooglePlayServices.cs:19)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159135/instance-was-not-initialized-using-default-configuration

Comment: Saw it. i have linked the keystore.